# Why does flutter MaterialApp Widget gives the error "not enough required arguments"

Tags: android, dart, flutter

The MaterialApp flutter widget is giving the error "1 required arguments expected, but 0 found" for the first flutter project available with the flutter sdk. I'm running it on VScode. And here is the code. Thanks in Advance.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(   // This line is giving Error at'('
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems odd, have you tried running it from scratch rather than a hot restart if that's an option. Are there any other clues on the lines before/after the error ?

Comment: yeah. i have tried everything including running it from scratch,reopening the project and reopening the editor.

Comment: Have you potentially defined another class with the name `MaterialApp`?

Comment: Nope, there is no other Widget named after that. Moreover, its the flutter code which you get after starting a new flutter project made by the flutter team for beginners. And I have also tried re-installing the flutter plugins, as well as VScode itself. I have also tried it on Android Studio.

Comment: Which flutter version you are using?

Comment: I'm currently using Flutter v0.11.9 but the problem exists with previous versions too. I have rechecked it by setting up the older Flutter sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue using VSCode and found this which fixed the problem:

Run the following commands in the Flutter install directory:

- git clean -xfd
- git stash save --keep-index
- git stash drop
- git pull
- flutter doctor

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted